# iOS 13 - PHImageManager returns a downscaled image for My Photo Stream photos

Tags: ios, ios13, photokit, photostream

Since iOS 13 I can't get original-res versions of photos in My Photo Stream using PhotoKit. I've had several complaints from users over the last few months, so it's not anything specific to my own device or account. The following code always retreives very small images (e.g. 360 x 480).

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ status in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if status == .authorized {

            // if iCloud Photo Library is disabled and Photo Stream is enabled this will give you My Photo Stream
            let photoStream = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .albumMyPhotoStream, options: nil)
            if let photoStreamCollection = photoStream.firstObject {

                let res = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: photoStreamCollection, options: nil)
                if let asset = res.firstObject {

                    let opts = PHImageRequestOptions()
                    opts.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
                    opts.isSynchronous = true
                    opts.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
                    opts.resizeMode = .exact

                    print("asset size: \(asset.pixelWidth) x \(asset.pixelHeight)")

                    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .default, options: opts) { (img, info) in
                        if let img = img {
                            print("image size: \(img.size.width * img.scale) x \(img.size.height * img.scale)")
                        }
                    }

                    PHImageManager.default().requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: asset, options: opts) { (imgData, dateUTI, orientation, info) in
                        if let imgData = imgData {
                            if let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                                print("image size: \(img.size.width * img.scale) x \(img.size.height * img.scale)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Console:
**asset size: 1536 x 2048

2020-02-02 08:18:44.452620-0700 photostreamphoto[7370:2576203] [ImageManager] [RM]: 1-1-0 Failed to decode image

2020-02-02 08:18:44.468675-0700 photostreamphoto[7370:2576203] [ImageManager] [RM]: 1-1-0 Failed to decode image

2020-02-02 08:18:44.479691-0700 photostreamphoto[7370:2576203] [ImageManager] [RM]: 1-1-0 Failed to decode image

image size: 360.0 x 480.0

2020-02-02 08:18:44.485069-0700 photostreamphoto[7370:2576203] [ImageManager] [RM]: 1-2-0 Failed to load image from URL:   file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoStreamsData/267078714/100APPLE/IMG_0001.JPG

2020-02-02 08:18:44.490447-0700 photostreamphoto[7370:2576203] [ImageManager] [RM]: 1-2-0 Failed to load image from URL:   file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoStreamsData/267078714/100APPLE/IMG_0001.JPG

2020-02-02 08:18:44.501745-0700 photostreamphoto[7370:2576203] [ImageManager] [RM]: 1-2-0 Failed to load image from URL:   file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoStreamsData/267078714/100APPLE/IMG_0001.JPG

image size: 360.0 x 480.0**

I've tried every conceivable combination of options in PHRequestOptions. Note that if I set `opts.version = .original` it gives me a nil image and nil image data.

I've also tried `asset.requestContentEditingInput(...)` to try to access the image URL directly:

```
let editingOpts = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
editingOpts.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
editingOpts.canHandleAdjustmentData = { data in
    return true
}
asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: editingOpts) { input, info in
    if let input = input, let url = input.fullSizeImageURL {
        let path = url.path
        let fm = FileManager.default
        if fm.fileExists(atPath: path) {
            // doesn't reach this
        }
    }
}
```

Console:

**2020-02-02 08:26:49.641787-0700 photostreamphoto[7416:2578984] [PhotoKit] Asset resource file URL not reachable, may have been pruned, will attempt availability change request**

Interestingly, UIImagePicker does retrieve the original-res image (e.g. 1536 x 2048). The Photos app also shows the full-res image. I wish I knew what black magic they're using.

If anyone knows of a workaround, please share.

Comment: Have you tried `opts.resizeMode = .none`?

Comment: @PaulSchröder thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I've tried that :(

Comment: Have you tried 1) defining `targetSize` as 1536 x 2048 or whatever size you are expection, or 2) delivery mode `oportunistic` with `async`, or 3) the request method `requestImageDataAndOrientation(for:options:resultHandler:)` ?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried those too.

Comment: @DevinPitcher, did you ever solve this? Getting the same in iOS 14

Comment: @DevinPitcher We submitted a bug report and Apple has fixed the issue for us in the iOS 14.5 Beta.